# Theme Problem when Dark Mode is activated under MIUI 11 / 12

Tags: colors, nativescript

EDIT: MIUI force Dark Mode to be activated in my app, so the app looks awful.

In some Part of my app when I set Color to "white", it will be shown as White.

If I set it as "gray", it will be shown as Gray.

If I set it as "red", it will be shown as Red.

but: If I set it as "black", it will be "WHITE!"

How can I solve this problem??

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Solution is Found!

Setting false to the `<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">true</item>`
in `App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`

Thanks to this link:
https://medium.com/@kivind/nativescript-disabling-dark-mode-382e5dfd11bd

so style.xml should looks like:

```
    <style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/NativeScriptToolbarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Nope, that does not work for me. MIUI 12.04 Global. Android 10.

Comment: Make sure that AppThemeBase is your theme in Manifest, like this:
android:theme="@style/AppThemeBase"
You may also want to make a separate theme in res/values-v29 to keep
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>

Comment: @Pixza I am using MIUI 12 and it works fine. Please chill

Comment: Works for me! Important to set it to `false`, blindly copied the true :D

Comment: <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item> requires API level 29. I have API level 21. How can I solve the issue of dark mode on Xiaomi ?

Comment: it might help @Ani : <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>

Comment: @Ani: <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
...<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="29">false</item>

Answer (score 21):

Meshing up many different solutions, I figured out this walktrough

`AppEntryPoint.kt`

```
class AppEntryPoint : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        /*in some XIAOMI devices seems to be necessary*/
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
    }
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:name=".AppEntryPoint"
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyMainTheme">
    ...
</application>
```

`themes.xml`

```
<style name="Theme.MyMainTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>

</style>
```

I don't know if it is the correct solution, but now it works for me.
There's maybe a strange way to manage this kind of behaviour in some Xiaomi devices...

Hope this answer could be useful also to others

Comment: So useful! I've been beating my head against the desk for 3 days over colours mysteriously changing without any apparent reason. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74540853/colour-coming-out-wrong-when-painting-on-android-canvas/74555562#74555562 Thanks

Answer (score -1):

On xiaomi redmi 9 at least had got to set this value false on both night and day themes.xml files. and work like a charm.

Comment: What value has to be set???