# Xiaomi MI 9T Pro not displaying text colors like emulator jetpack-compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

**Problem**

I am trying to animate two colors switching between each other depending on some properties, now the code is done and works my emulator but not my Mi 9T Pro, I have not tested in any other device but I will once it's possible and I'l let you know if the behaviour is the same.

**Expected behaviour:**

Simple composable with color animations and the UI reacts to the changes accordingly

**Actual Behaviour(Emulator Pixel2 API 30)**

The colors are animated as expected and changed to the proper color as expected

**Actual Behaviour(MI 9T Pro)**

The colors are animated but are somewhat merged, hard colors are displayed more accurately, but softer colors are not.

**Emulator Theme Colors** Correct

[image: Theme Colors]

**Emulator Hard Colors** Correct

[image: Hard Colors])

**MI 9T Pro Theme Colors)** Wrong

[image]

**MI 9T Pro Hard Colors** Wrong

[image]

**Animation properties**

```
val animContentColor = animateColorAsState(
    targetValue = when {
        locallySelected -> onPrimaryColor()
        else -> onSurfaceColor()
    },
    animationSpec = colorAnimSpec
)

val animBackgroundColor = animateColorAsState(
    targetValue = when {
        locallySelected -> primaryColor()
        selected -> surface5Color()
        else -> surface1Color()
    },
    animationSpec = colorAnimSpec
)
```

**Composable**

```
ElevatedCard(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    contentColor = animContentColor.value,
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(48.dp)
            .background(color = animBackgroundColor.value)
            .clickable(onClick = onClick),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {

        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = selected,
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Check,
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 16.dp)
            )
        }

        Text(
            text = theater.name,
            style = TypographyMaterial3.bodyMedium,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(start = 16.dp)
        )

        Text(
            text = "15km",
            style = TypographyMaterial3.labelSmall,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
        )

    }
}
```

**Question**

Is it possible that this could be a device issue?

**Edit**
I have tested it on a Huawei Phone and works as expected so I'm convinced this might be an issue with the Xiaomi device/style

**Solution**

[Theme Problem when Dark Mode is activated under MIUI 11 / 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62696305/theme-problem-when-dark-mode-is-activated-under-miui-11-12/62732689#62732689)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be "Material You" - whatever API level that MI 9T Pro may be.

eg. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrfuHyMlehc

Comment: You were right, it's a thing with XIAOMI, I have to work on my google skills